# How to color terminal output with variable name in another variable

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, colors

So I want to color my terminal output but nothing works for me. I have script with code and txt file which I read input from. It looks something like this:

**example.txt**

```
                                    ${BLUE}_.
                            _/=\:<
                          .#/*${RED}let}
                        //as\@#:~/
                       try()|:-./
                      ${BLUE}*~let${RED}:>${BLUE}@{#
                      </>}#@~*/
                     ${RED}(+!:~/+/
                     /={+|
-
```

**script.sh**

```
BLUE="\033[0;34m"
RED="\033[0;31m"
# print example.txt but colored
```

Comment: I would only use this if you are absolutely sure that example.txt cannot contain malicious code: `eval echo -e "$line"`

Comment: This works with this example but it won't with my code because in actual txt file are lines that look like this: `(@+_let#do/.@#=#>[/]#let=#or@\=<()~if)*<)\)`. It's not code just string code-styled and I don't want to run it just print it.

Comment: Do you want to output only one line at a time in your loop or do you want to do more?

Comment: please update the question to show more sample inputs that are more representative of your real files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply as:

```bash
BLUE=$'\033[0;34m' RED=$'\033[0;31m' envsubst < example.txt
```

By having the ANSI sequences directly in the environment variables, rather than escape codes, this relieves the need to un-escape the whole file content. ANSI sequences are already encoded.

Now, a more portable approach would be, to get the actual sequences from `tput` commands, rather than hard-coded ANSI.

```bash
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4) RED=$(tput setaf 1) envsubst < example.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and `envsubst`:

```
export BLUE="\033[0;34m"
export RED="\033[0;31m"
printf "%b\n" "$(envsubst <example.txt)"
```

See: `man envsubst`

Comment: Works almost perfect! But is there a way to prevent it from escaping characters like \v or \n that may happen in example.txt or do I have to change \v to \\v in example.txt?

Comment: @szym See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73284599/7939871) for how to not interpret back-slashes as escape sequences in the `example.txt` file.